# ColdFusion S3 directoryList throws this error "An error occurred when performing a file operation listFiles"

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-s3

If I try to list the files in an S3 directory using the built-in S3 integration in ColdFusion 9, I get an exception when any of the files contains a % (percent) character. The full error message looks like this:

> An error occurred when performing a file operation listFiles on file
>   /activities/18057/files.
>
> The cause of this exception was:
>   org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Unknown message with code
>   "Invalid URI escape sequence "%ui"."..

I think this is a ColdFusion bug caused by overzealous character escaping, but can anyone with S3 integration try it themselves to confirm? I'm literally just doing this:

```
<cfset var files = directoryList("s3://my.bucket.path/somefolder/")/>
```

It works find for "normal" files, but fails as soon as one of the files has a % in its filename.

Comment: Does it work if you use `%25` instead?

Comment: @PeterBoughton It works fine and, interestingly, the file name that directoryList returns is unmodified. Apparently the file is checked for (erroneously) illegal characters, but no escaping of % characters is actually performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would appear to be a "bug" in Adobe CF9 (ACF9). If it's not a bug, it's certainly odd behavior as I tried the code in Railo 3.3.3.0001 (current release) and it works perfectly.

I got the same error from ACF9 as you. In addition, ACF10 has the same error. I also tried in OpenBD but was not able to read the desired folder in my bucket (it read the main bucket, its files and listed the folder but was not able to get inside the folder). However, I've not used OpenBD a lot so this was probably more my error than anything else.

Comment: I'll submit it as a bug to Adobe. I appreciate the additional Railo test - one more reason to switch.

Comment: No problem, Rupert. I migrated a pretty darn big app from CF to Railo and it was not too bad at all ... and it's been rock-solid since the transition. With no intended knock on ACF at all, I'm definitely a fan of Railo.

Comment: Rupert, did you log a bug? I can't find it.